# Why don't CFLs heat up?

Tags: atomic-physics

When there's a lightning the air ionizes and becomes very hot. I've read that the CFLs (Compact Fluorescent Lamps) work the same way by ionising the gas in the bulb. Then why don't CFLs become that hot?

Comment: CFLs *do* get hot, and can get *very* hot, so this question isn't really answerable.

Comment: I know they get hot, but not as hot as the air gets during a lightning. Why?

Comment: Ah, I see. That's more clear then.

Answer (score 1):

CFL's work by trickling a relatively small amount of electrical current through ionized mercury vapor, which causes the vapor to emit UV light. Phosphors that coat the inside walls of the CFL tube then convert the UV to visible light.

Once the tube is turned on, the current flowing through the vapor is limited so as to generate mostly UV light via the line emission of the mercury and as little thermal emission via ohmic heating of the vapor as possible.

In contrast, when electricity flows through ionized air during a lightning strike, there is no means of limiting the (peak) current so as to limit the heating of the ionized air. Currents in excess of a million amps can flow and in response the ionized air gets hot enough to become incandescent.

Answer (score 0):

**Because CFLs use Mercury vapor inside its tubes**

The difference you notice is due to the difference of specific heat capacity of atmospheric air and Mercury vapor

Answer (score -3):

they are made of semiconductors

Comment: No, they aren't. You're thinking of an LED, perhaps?